# Не запускается проект на ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core

Пишу в консоле `dotnet build`. Выдает ошибку

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\***\web-application.dll' 
because it is being used by another process
```

Comment: Наверно его еще не отпустил предыдущий dotnet run

Comment: А вообще [гугл рулит](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows)